# Autohotkey - Copy from HTML and paste in Word

Tags: autohotkey

I am new to Autohotkey, so need your patience.

I have a folder with 6236 individual HTML files; each contains one sentence.

The names of these files go like this: 001001, 001002, 001003,..., 001007, 002001,002002, 002003 and so on. Of course, with .html file format.

I want to write a script with hotstrings such as:

`:*:001001::`

`:*:001002::`

and so on, so that when I type 001001 in Word, have the content of 001001.html pasted into the word. And when I type 001002 it pastes the content of 001002.html into the word. This way for all the 6236 files.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Pass the hotstring itself (plus .html suffix) to a fileread command, then send the contents from the variable holding what was read.  Try it along with the ahk help at https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileRead.htm, and ask for help.

Comment: This question is answered on the AutoHotkey forum here https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=46447

Answer (score 0):

Main code

```
 loop,6236
 {
 number := 001000 + A_Index
 number := "00" . number
 temptext1 :=":*:" . number . "::"
 temptext2 := "FileRead, orgtext, C:\" . number . ".html"
 temptext3 := "SendInput % orgtext"
 temptext4 := "return"
 temptext := temptext . temptext1 . "`n" . temptext2 . "`n" . temptext3 . "`n" . temptext4 . "`n`n"
 }

FileAppend, %temptext%, C:\test.ahk
```

Loop 1 will create following text

```
:*:001001::
FileRead, orgtext, C:\001001.html
SendInput % orgtext
return
```

Loop 2 will create

```
:*:001002::
FileRead, orgtext, C:\001002.html
SendInput % orgtext
return
```

And so on until 007236. You need to change where your html files are located. I assumed C:\001001.html. If for example files are in C:\Program Files\Myhtmlfiles\001001.html then edit line 6 into:

```
temptext2 := "FileRead, orgtext, C:\Program Files\Myhtmlfiles\" . number . ".html"
```

This is quite a long loop so it takes a couple of seconds to finish. After the loop is finished result gets saved into test.ahk located in C:\

Comment: The above will send the HTML code, not the HTML formatted text, so <b>bold text</b> vs **bold text**. As described on the forum you can use the WinClip() library to do that.